# Showing $G$ is infinite cyclic (or otherwise)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a group $G$ which has an infinite cyclic normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. We write $G/H$ as $\{H,gH\}$ for $g \notin H$.

Then suppose $g^2 \neq e$. So, we know $g^2 \in H$, but $g$ has infinite order.

I believe that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$, but I haven't been able to come up with a complete argument. For example, it looks like $H$ corresponds to the even numbers, and $gH$ corresponds to the odd numbers, but I have yet to show that $G$ is abelian. If it is not necessarily the case that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$, feel free to ignore everything from here onwards.

In particular, I wish to show that $\langle g \rangle$ commutes with $H$. Sure, I know that $\langle g^2 \rangle$ commutes with $H$ since $\langle g^2 \rangle \subseteq H$, but I cannot do the same for $\langle g \rangle$. All I'm certain of is that $gh = h'g$ for $h,h' \in H$; I have not been able to show that $h = h'$.

I've also tried using commutators ($[G,G]$ is contained in $H$), but I'm unsure if this is even helpful. For example, $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = (h')h^{-1}$, but again I hit the same wall as above.

Another guess is somehow using the quotient group (like $ghH = (gH)(hH) = (hH)(gH) = hgH$) but I believe that's faulty. Any ideas on how to proceed here?

**Note**: I preferably do not want to use results regarding finitely generated abelian groups, because this should be doable without it. No need for homomorphisms or automorphisms, either (not that I'm certain they'd help).

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1037835/356200) is closely related, but not quite the same; and it is unanswered at the time of posting this question.

Comment: You know that $g$ commutes with $g^2 \ne 1$. The only automorphism of ${\mathbb Z}$ of order $2$ is the one that  sends every element to its inverse, and conjugation by $g$ cannot induce that (because $g$ does not invert $g^2$), so $g$ must centralize $H$, and $G$ is indeed abelian. But it need not be cyclic, as the example of Keith Kearnes shows.

Comment: Why can't $G \simeq \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$? EDIT: I missed your additional requirement that $g^2 \neq e$.

Comment: It can be $Z \oplus Z_2$ (which is abelian).

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the explanation. I just considered something: Taking $H = \langle h \rangle$, if $g^2 = h$ (and if $G$ is abelian), then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$, I believe. I wonder if we can classify the cases for $g^2 = h^n$ for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Since $G$ is abelian, the only possibilities are $Z$ (when $n$ is odd) and $Z \oplus Z_2$.(when $n$ is even).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$, $H = \mathbb Z\times \{0\}$,  and $g=(1,1)$.

---

Edit 10/29/16: I will respond to a comment.

Assume that $[G:H]=2$, $H$ is infinite cyclic, and $g\in G-H$. As Derek Holt has already mentioned, the action of $g$ by conjugation on $H$ is an automorphism that fixes $g^2\in H$. If $g^2\neq e$, then this automorphism must be the identity. In this case $G$ is abelian. The contrapositive statement is that: if $G$ is nonabelian, then any $g\in G-H$ satisfies $g^2=e$. In this case, choose $g\in G-H$ and let $C=\langle g\rangle$. $C$ is a complement of $H$, so $G$ is a nonabelian semidirect product of an infinite cyclic group by a 2-element group. In this case, $G$ must be the infinite dihedral group.

Thus, if $G$ is not the infinite dihedral group, then $G$ is abelian. If $g^2\in H$ has a square root in $H$, that is, if $g^2=h^2$ for some $h\in H$, then $g_1:=gh^{-1}\in G-H$ satisfies $g_1^2=e$. Hence 
$C=\langle g_1\rangle$ is a complement of $H$, so $G$ is a product of an infinite cyclic group and a $2$-element group. In this case, $G\cong \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$.

Finally, if $G$ is neither of the two groups mentioned, then it is an abelian group, and for any $g\in G-H$ the element $g^2 (\in H)$ does not have a square root in $H$. If $H = \langle h\rangle$, then $g^2$ must be an odd power of $h$, say $g^2=h^{2r+1}$. Then $g_2:=gh^{-r}\in G-H$ and $\langle g_2\rangle$ contains $g_2^2 = h$ and $g_2^{2r+1} = g_2(h^r) = g$, so $\langle g_2\rangle = \langle h,g\rangle = G$. This proves that $G$ is cyclic in this last case.

Comment: One thing that confuses me here: where does the element $(0,1)$ belong? It has order 2, when I thought every element in $G$ has infinite order. Furthermore, the only non-trivial element in $G$ that is not in $H$ is $g$ (and the odd powers of $g$, but $(0,1)$ is not an odd power of $(1,1)$), so there shouldn't be another... am I missing something?

Comment: The issue concerns how things are quantified. When you write "We write $G/H$ as $\{H,gH\}$ for $g\notin H$. Then suppose $g^2\neq e$. So, we know $g^2\in H$, but $g$ has infinite order", do you mean **there exists** $g$ such that $G/H = \{H,gH\}$ and $g^2\neq e$, or do you mean **for every** $g$ such that $G/H=\{H,gH\}$ we have $g^2\neq e$? Different quantifiers lead to different answers.

Comment: I suppose it would be "there exists", since I meant it as a particular such $g$.

Comment: Suppose $[G:H]=2$ and $H$ is infinite cyclic. Call $g$ _relevant_ if $G=\{H,gH\}$, and call $g$ _good_ if $g^2\neq e$. Now, if $G\cong \mathbb Z$, then all relevant $g$ are good. If $G\cong D_{\infty}$, then no relevant $g$ is good. If $G\cong \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$, then some relevant $g$ are good and some are not. In the last case, $g=(1,1)$ is relevant and good, while $g=(0,1)$ is relevant and not good.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll accept your answer for now. But how would we show that $G$ must be one of these, then? Particularly, in your example, if $H = \langle h \rangle$, then $(gh)^2 = e$. Is it necessary that $gh$ can only have order $2$ or infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Take the infinite dihedral group, which is very similar to the group in the deleted answer:

$$\;D_\infty=\Bbb Z\rtimes\Bbb Z_2\;\text{,  and the action}\;\;x^a=x^{-1}\;,\;\;\Bbb Z_2=\langle a\rangle\;,\;\;\Bbb Z=\langle x\rangle\;$$

This already gives you a counterexample to what you believe.

But that we can also write $\;D_\infty=\langle a,x\;/\;a^2=1,\,x^a=x^{-1}\rangle\;$, and forget now the semi direct product written above.

Now you prove: $\;H:=\langle x\rangle\;$ has index two and thus...

Comment: But what are you going to take as your element $g$? The problem with this example is that $g^2=1$ for all $g \not\in H$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Indeed I didn't...most probably finger slip. Thanks.

Comment: @DerekHolt True, I oversaw that condition. Well, perhaps someone else will come with something else.